# Computing hashes in PostgreSQL for JSONB columns

Tags: postgresql, hashing, jsonb

From [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT):

> `jsonb` does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.

I have a `jsonb` column that contains some data. I extract specific key data (which is also json) and hash it using sha256, something like:

```sql
SELECT sha256(to_jsonb(rule_element) :: TEXT :: BYTEA);
```

Where `rule_element` was extracted from the original data. Given that it does not maintain order of keys and the original column of `jsonb` may be updated in the future, I do not think it is safe to compute hashes as they might change.

Can I compute consistent hashes for `jsonb` columns? (99% Sure you can't, 1% hope to make my work easier)

The hashes would be used for unique identification purposes, basically acting as a unique key for different types of JSON compositions.

Comment: How about sorting `jsonb` keys prior to hashing, anyone?

Comment: Does `jsonb` give consistent output for same input in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official guarantee that the implementation (and the text representation) of `jsonb` won't change, so I wouldn't depend on the stability of such hashes if I am dealing with data that will be used 50 years from now.

However, if the on-disk representation of `jsonb` changed, that would be a release that breaks upgrade with `pg_upgrade`, so it is not likely to happen anytime soon. The string representation could of course change, but I cannot think of a reason to change that unless the on-disk representation of `jsonb` changes.

If you want to use the hashes in a unique constraint you could create a unique constraint on `jsonb_hash_extended(jsoncol, 0)`.  As long as you only store the hashes in a ways that wouldn't break if the hash values change during a dump/restore.  I would feel unsafe about using those hashes as immutable identifiers outside the database.

But perhaps I am too worried: if the result of `jsonb_hash_extended()` would change in a different PostgreSQL version, then hash partitioning in `jsonb` would break during an upgrade. So perhaps we can never change that anyway.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77830609/15412365. 

The hashes would be used for unique identification purposes, basically acting as a unique key for different types of JSON compositions.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about `jsonb_hash` and `jsonb_hash_extended`. Why can't we just `jsonb_hash` to get a unique hash value? As long as the actual JSON in `jsonb` doesn't change, anyhow it may be represented, it should give a consistent unique value, right?

Comment: > As long as you only store the hashes in a way that wouldn't break if the hash values change during a dump/restore.



Why would the hash values change during dump/restore? I was thinking to get consistent hash output for *logically* same JSON, was something like sorting all the keys and then finding the hash value. `jsonb` -> sort -> sorted and consistent -> hash.

Comment: I am not understanding the complete picture and your concerns over here, can you please elaborate? Really appreciate you taking out time.

Comment: "Why would the hash values change during dump/restore?" Because the implementation might change (unlikely as it is). Sure, if you come up with your own hashing algorithm that processes the keys and values in some well-defined order, that would be truly immutable.

Comment: The implementation change would mean breaking compatibility upgrade. In that case, if internal structure is changed, shouldn't the output of `jsonb_hash` and `jsonb_hash_extended` be the same as internal processing of that will also change.

Comment: Btw I'm just assuming what `jsonb_hash_extended` just takes another value, somewhat like a salt to generate a hash, am I right?

Comment: We are theorizing about potential changes. So I cannot tell for certain.

Comment: What would you suggest? A) Do sorting and then hash. B) Just use inbuilt hash functions, hopefully, nothing will break in the future.

Comment: I wouldn't enforce uniqueness on JSON values. I think that is a design problem. But if I had to, I would use the built-in hash functions, make sure that they are not used anywhere outside the database, and that a dump/restore will work even if the hash values change.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot!